# Expo (React Native): Statusbar is not showing on android and adds a padding top

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When running the app with **expo go**, it's working fine on Android, but when I test it with the pre-release build, it remove the clock and adds a padding.

#### This is what I see when running on expo go and also what I want

1. Notice it show the Statusbar with the clock and notifications
2. Notice there's no space between the Statusbar and the image

[image: img]

#### This is what I get once I install the pre-release build

1. Notice it doesn't show the Statusbar
2. Notice the padding top that shouldn't be there

[image: img]

#### MainLayout

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View} from 'react-native';
import Constants from "expo-constants";

export default function MainLayout({children}) {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={[styles.screen]}>
            <View
                style={[styles.view]}
            >
                {children}
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        flex: 1,
    },
    view: {
        flex: 1,
    }
});
```

I think the padding top is caused by this line `paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight` but I assume it won't be an issue anymore once the StatusBar will be fixed.

Note 1: It's working as expected on iOS.

Note 2: I did see this component: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/status-bar/
But based on my understanding, the default expo configuration should be what I expect (?) I tried anyway, but with no luck. I'm open to give a second chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally succeeded.

First I tried to add this to my `app.config.js`

```js
"androidStatusBar": {
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
    "barStyle": "dark-content",
    "translucent": true,
    "hidden": false
},
```

It did somehow worked, but the bar was grayed-out. When compiling I had a message that `androidStatusBar.backgroundColor` was conflicting with `splash.backgroundColor`

My assumption is that the splash screen change the status bar style when starting the application. So all I needed to do was to update the status bar once the app is started.

But now that I knew the configuration, I re-tried by removing the config above and re-adding `expo-status-bar`, but this time with the same configuration that what I had in `androidStatusBar`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View} from 'react-native';
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import {StatusBar} from "expo-status-bar";

export default function MainLayout({children}) {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={[styles.screen]}>
            <View
                style={[styles.view]}
            >
                {children}
            </View>
            <StatusBar style="dark"
                       translucent={true}
                       hidden={false}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        flex: 1,
    },
    view: {
        flex: 1,
    }
});
```

- `style`: has to be `dark` because "dark" is for the content, not the bar.
- `translucent`: has to be `true`. The doc says it's true by default, but I suppose the splash screen changed it to false.
- `hidden`: Not sure if this is needed, but to this point, I prefer specified it.

As a final note: The reason the app was pushed down was specified in the [translucent](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#translucent) documentation

> (boolean) - Sets android:windowTranslucentStatus in styles.xml. **When false, the system status bar pushes the content of your app down** (similar to position: relative). **When true, the status bar floats above the content in your app** (similar to position: absolute). Defaults to true to match the iOS status bar behavior (which can only float above content).